# List of functions to be a applied

Tags: clojure

I'm new to clojure and want to accomplish the following:

I have some functions with a one letter name, a string "commands" 
and an argument arg

```
(defn A [x] ...)
(defn B [x] ...)
(defn C [x] ...)
```

I want to have a function (let's call it `apply-fns`) that, given the string with the names of the functions, applies the function to the given argument in order:

```
; commands = "ACCBB"    
(apply-fns commands arg)
;should have the same effect as
(B (B (C (C (A arg)))))
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: `((comp b b c c a) arg)`?

Comment: (defn all [cmds] (apply comp (map (comp resolve symbol str) (reverse cmds)))) gives a function that does (C (B (A ...))) on its argument when cmds is "ABC". Works fine in leiningen but gives a null pointer exception on codingame.com. Sort of frustrating ...

But I've learned the comp command. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your aim is to apply a series of functions (in order), so that the following function is applied to the result of the previous one. The result should be the same as nesting the forms (i.e., function calls), like in your example: `(B (B (C (C (A arg)))))`

If you can use a sequence of the commands (or can extract the sequence from the string representation `"ACCBB"`), you can accomplish this by reducing over the functions, which are named as *commands* in the example.

```
(def commands [A C C B B])

(defn apply-all [initial commands]
  (reduce #(%2 %1) initial commands))
```

A fuller example:

```
(defn A [x]
  (str x "A"))

(defn B [x]
  (str x "B"))

(defn C [x]
  (str x "C"))  

(def commands [A C C B B])

(defn apply-all [initial commands]
  (reduce #(%2 %1) initial commands))

user=> (apply-all "" commands)
; => "ACCBB"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do. Thanks for rewording it. To get the list of functions from a string I added:

(defn cmds [string] (map (comp resolve symbol str) string))

(apply-all "x" (cmds "ABB"))

works fine in the leinigen REPL shell, but (println (cmds "AB")) gives (nil nil) in the codingame.com IDE :( Could this be a name space issue?

Answer (score 2):

Being a literal genie, I'll give you exactly what you're asking:

```
(defn A [x])
(defn B [x])
(defn C [x])

(def commands "AACCBB")

(defmacro string-fns [arg]
  (let [cs (map (comp symbol str) commands)]
    `(-> ~arg ~@cs)))

(comment

  (macroexpand
   '(string-fns :foo)) ;;=> (B (B (C (C (A (A :foo))))))

  )
```

Without any context, however, this makes no sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to do this puzzle on codingame.com https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/folding-paper Have done it in python and java and it seems to be easy enough for a clojure greenhorn. I've done the LRUD functions to fold a paper and now I'm trying to call them in the order given by the input string. Of course one can do it in an if-else cascade but that doesn't look like clojure. Still a lot to learn ...